# Algorithm to convert string to int while mainting lexicographical order

Tags: algorithm, lexicographic

I need an algorithm that will map a string of length four to a four digit number.  The problem is it has to maintain lexicographical order.  It doesn't need to not have collisions, it's just that if S <= T, F(S) <= F(T).  The only additional constraint is that it should be surjective: all numbers must be mapped to by some string.

Comment: Surely F(S) = 9999 is not what you're looking for, yet it satisfies the constraints.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Good catch.  The other constraint was that it's surjective: all numbers can be produced.

Comment: Ah. What exactly is the domain of F, then? (e.g., strings of length exactly four, comprised entirely of characters in the class `[A-Za-z]`)

Comment: Assuming characters are integers between MIN and MAX inclusively: `y[i]=(x[i]-MIN)*10/(MAX-MIN+1)` (not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just map letters to digits directly, grouping a few at a time to handle the fact that there are more letters than digits?  `{a, b, c} => 1, {d, e, f} => 2` etc.